# How can I detect if a screen is touch sensitive?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, touch

I am developing an application for Windows 8 (Metro UI). I am using HTML5, JavaScript, jQuery etc for development. I want to show a different user interface if the screen does not support  screen touch events.

How can I detect if screen support touch sensitive in Windows 8 using JavaScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See here: [Detecting Touch Hardware in IE 10](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/detecting-touch-hardware-ie-10)

From the above page:

> In order to test for touch in Internet Explorer 10, which will ship
>   with the first batch of Windows 8 tablets later this year, you can
>   call the window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints method

```
if (window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {
// touch device
}
else {
// non-touch device
}
```

Comment: IE 11 seems to support touch events such as `pointerdown` or `pointermove`. Is this solution working for Windows 8 with IE 11 as well? Or will it detect as a touch device?
MS docs only talk about IE 10...